# Magento: Can't get categories children

Tags: magento

For some reason this code is returning NULL when trying to get a categories subcategories.

```
 <?php var_dump($_category->getChildrenCategories()); ?>
```

Here is the full code from a .phmtl file.

```
<ul id="nav_vert">
            <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
            <?php if ($_category->getIsActive()) { ?>
            <?php $open = $this->isCategoryActive($_category); ?>
            <?php $potential = $_category->hasChildren(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category); ?>"<?php if($open) { echo ' class="open"'; } ?><?php if($potential) { echo ' class="potential"'; } ?> ><?php if($potential&&$open) { echo 'v '; } elseif($potential) { echo '> '; }else{ echo '  '; }?><?php echo $_category->getName();?></a>
                <?php if ($open && $potential): ?>
                <?php var_dump($_category->getChildrenCategories()); ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($_category->getChildrenCategories() as $subcategory): ?>
                    <?php $subCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcategory); ?>
                    <?php $open = $this->isCategoryActive($subCat); ?>
                    <?php $potential = $subCat->hasChildren(); ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($subCat); ?>"<?php if($open) { echo ' class="subopen"'; } ?><?php if($potential) { echo ' class="potential"'; } ?><?php if(!$potential&&$open) { echo ' class="final"'; } ?> ><?php if($potential&&$open) { echo ':: '; } elseif($potential) { echo '> '; }?><?php echo $subCat->getName(); ?> (<?php echo $subCat->getProductCount(); ?>)</a>
                        <?php if ($open && $potential): ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ($subcategory->getChildrenCategories() as $subsubcategory): ?>
                            <?php $subsubCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subsubcategory); ?>
                            <?php $open = $this->isCategoryActive($subsubCat) ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($subsubCat); ?>" <?php if($open) { echo ' class="final"'; } ?>><?php echo $subsubCat->getName(); ?> (<?php echo $subsubCat->getProductCount(); ?>)</a></li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
```

This line always returns true

```
<?php $potential = $_category->hasChildren(); ?>
```

And I know that the category has children.

Can anyone suggest why this doesn't work?

This is how I place the phtml in the page:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.vertnav" template="catalog/navigation/vert_nav.phtml" before="-" />
</reference>
```

Magento version 1.5.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `$_category->getChildren()` (instead of `$_category->getChildrenCategories()` )

Have an easy day, 
Pesach

Comment: I orginally had getChildren but it seems to crash the page. I read somewhere they changed it from getChildren to getChildrenCategories at some point?

Comment: If you're attempting `var_dump($subcategory)` then it definitely will crash the page, or at least run out of memory. Use `var_dump($subcategory->debug())` instead and you might find that `getChildren` is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You might also like to try this,

```
foreach ($_category->getCategories($_category) as $subcategory):
```

[`getCategories()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Category.html#getCategories) is a more complex form but it allows you more control too. By specifying a recursion level you can retrieve not just the children but grand-children too...

Comment: I tried your function but ````<?php var_dump($_category->getCategories($_category)); ?>```` returns NULL too. I'm beginning to think the block doens't have access to these methods?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code,

```
$this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories()
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
 <?php $categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
  <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
    <?php $subcategories = $category->getChildren() ?>
      <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
        <?php $subsubcategories = $subcategory->getChildren() ?>
         <?php foreach($subsubcategories as $subsubcategory): ?>
         <?php endforeach; ?><!-- end foreach subsubcategories -->
      <?php endforeach; ?><!-- end foreach subcategories -->
  <?php endforeach; ?><!-- end foreach categories -->
```

This is the basic idea behind extracting children categories.
So accordingly you can work on it.