# How to retrieve all the functions that we can apply to an object/item In Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I'm actually setting up a SiteMap on My website, I already have a sitemap.xml but I'm wondering how to build up a page like this one : http://beta.brickhousesecurity.com/ancillary/sitemap.do

So I've been into template/catalagog/seo/sitemap.phtml and tried to figure out how to retrieve the subcategories (and its childs) for all the Categories.

So I got

```
<?php $_items = $this->getCollection(); 
    $token=1;
?>
<?php if($_items->getSize()): ?>
    <ul class="sitemap">
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getItemUrl($_item) ?>"><?php echo $_item->name ?></a></li>
    </ul>
```

But I don't know how to organize it like in the link I gave above.

therefore I'm wondering how could I know all the functions I can apply to $_item ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try print_r(get_class_methods($_item)). Is that what you mean?

Comment: I tried to use it but when I try 'echo 'getName ; '.$_item->getName()."</br>";' or a print_r, it doesnt return anything or it crashes. How could I organize it like a tree (just like in my example)? Is '$this->getCollection(); ' the wrong way to do so ? Cause I found that : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388265/magento-cant-get-categories-children#comment10356712_8389421)  but he doesnt use the same method .
Thanks !